# If I reference List A to List B, I do changes on List B, would it affect List A?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list called `ListA`: `List<string> allStuffs = ...`

I want to reference the list to `ListB` as `List<string> secondList = allStuffs;`

If I do something like `secondList.Remove(someitem)`, would it also remove the same item on `allStuffs`?

Comment: why not simply try it out yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; there is only one list object in this example - whatever the `...` is on the first line. The `List<string> secondList = allStuffs;` doesn't create a new *list* - it just creates a new *reference*, with the value copied from `allStuffs` - which is itself just a reference (not the list itself).

You can have as many references to that list object as you like: they're all just indicators as to where the actual list is.

So if you follow one copy of the reference to the object to call `Remove`, the change will be visible from any other reference to the same object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't accept the answer for another 9 minutes. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Yes as explained in the above answer it is pointing to the same list. if you don't want to change the first list on change anything on the second then you can use it like this.

```
List<int> ls1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> ls2 = new List<int>(ls1);
ls2.Remove(1);
```

`ls1` will still have 1,2 and 3

Comment: Thank you so much! This is such a useful thing!